# State Variable needs to updated right after

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update the thankscreen state right after the load state but it does not work.

```
    const [load, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [thankscreen, setThankScreen] = useState(false)

    const finish = async(e) =>{
      e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission
      setLoading(true);
      await sendMessage(email);
      closeCheckout(); // Close the checkout popup
      effect(); // Update the cart data
      console.log("AFTER UPDATING CART")
      setLoading(false)
      console.log("after setting setLoading")
      setThankScreen(true)
      console.log("after setting ThankyouScneen")
    }
```

Comment: State updates are asynchronous. In order to see the state of 'thankScreen'. You can use a useEffect hook, and log the value. It won't show updated state in the same function.
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(variable);
  }, [variable]);

Comment: What's not working? What's happening instead? Please add more details to your question to explain what you mean by "it does not work".

Answer (score 1):

We are missing some information, what do u want to do exactly? The problem is, that sendMessage is an asynchronous function, it may take some time to complete, and the subsequent code after await sendMessage(email) will be executed before it finishes.

U can fix it with the useEffect hook. I would recommend u to learn the basic React Hooks before making ur own projects. A solution could look like this.

```js
const [load, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [thankscreen, setThankScreen] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (load) {
    // Here, you can perform the actions you want to execute after the load state has been set to true
    setThankScreen(true);
  }
}, [load]);

const finish = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission
  setLoading(true);

  try {
    await sendMessage(email);
    console.log("AFTER UPDATING CART");
    setLoading(false);
    console.log("after setting setLoading");
    closeCheckout(); // Close the checkout popup
    effect(); // Update the cart data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error occurred:", error);
    setLoading(false); // Reset loading state in case of error
  }
}
```